# Automatically install Adobe DNG Converter on Windows

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, installer

I'm trying to [install Adobe DNG Converter](http://supportdownloads.adobe.com/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=6167&fileID=6201) automatically, as it has to be installed on multiple windows Servers. I tried searching for this, but did not find anything describing how to do it. The servers have Chocolatey installed, but the DNG converter doesn't exist as a package.

Double clicking the .exe just opens a UI dialog with one button, "Install". After clicking this everything installs, and you have to click "Finish" at the end.

I've tried to [extract the installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681252/programmatically-extract-contents-of-installshield-setup-exe):

- `DNGConverter_9_10_1.exe /s /extract_all`
- `DNGConverter_9_10_1.exe /a /s /v"/qn /log TARGETDIR=\"C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\dng\""`
- `DNGConverter_9_10_1.exe /silent /stage_only ISRootStagePath="C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\dng\"`

but none of these does anything other than running the installer normally.

Is there anything else I can try to avoid the UI and automatically install the converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNG Converter installer was made using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusage).

On Windows 10 with the latest version of DNG Converter (10.0.0.827), this worked for me:

```
DNGConverter_10_0.exe /S
```

The `S` is upper-case, not lower-case. The command returned immediately and launched the installer silently in the background.